# Checks broken canine? (11)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Somee cryptic crosswords clues I have made:

Checks broken canine? (11)

Hint:

> Two meanings of canine are used here. This is a 'double straight'.

And a bonus:

Too many teeth? (5)

Hint:

> This is a 'double straight'

Comment: Please could you also tell us which letters you already know, and in which positions in the word?

Comment: Just to clarify, are these crossword clues you saw or that you wrote yourself? I'm having a hard time getting started!

Comment: `Veterinarian` would work quite well for the first clue (someone who would check a broken/injured canine/dog), but alas it is 12 letters :(

Comment: @arth I wrote them myself.

Comment: @RosieF these are indeed I wrote myself.  I hope this is tagged correctly.

Comment: Any chance of some hints here? ;)

Comment: @Arth my wish is your command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first one could be

> Houndstooth

since it

> addresses the meanings of canine.

However, it doesn't seem to fit too strongly with the clue as a whole (although it might work with the first word)

Comment: That's the solution. The pattern is often described as "broken checks".

Answer (score 1):

For the bonus, how about

> **tough**.

Because

> The "?" implies an unconventional reading of the clue. So perhaps the first definition is "too man-y" as in "like a man", which could be *tough*. Then the other definition is "teeth" and if something "has teeth" it's (at least idiomatically) *tough*.

Answer (score 0):

Checks broken canine? (11):

> **Orthodontic**
>  An Orthodontic treatment would be to check teeth including broken canine's.

Too many teeth? (5):

> **Natal**
>  Extra teeth in children are called Natal teeth

Comment: ... because ... ?

Comment: Both are the correct length

Comment: So are METAMERISMS and ARRAS (picking two words at random). Why are your answers better than those?

Comment: (I'm not saying they're wrong. Just that general practice here -- of which I strongly approve -- is that answers come with explanations of why they're right.)

Comment: An Orthodontic treatment would be to check teeth including broken canine's. And extra teeth in children are called Natal teeth

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan makes a fair point. Not only that, but the OP tagged this question cryptic-crosswords, and I don't see how either of the clues can be a *cryptic* clue for any of the answers suggested so far.